# How to distinguish between PCL data and usual Text?

Tags: c++, printer-control-language

Currently I try to distinguish between PCL and Text data, does someone know how to distinguish them properly? I have read that there are several PCL standards (PCL1 - PCL6), would this affect the detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could search for manuals of PCL1 to 6 and check the opening and closing tags (they are required).
If they are present you know it is pcl. If not, text.

You want more security?

You could write a class(or find one) special for decoding the PCL code and convert it to an image or something. If it fails, it is text.